# transform not working on css hover on a button element

Tags: html, css

I've got another problem on making the animated CSS button.
the button is suppose to be double in size but it is not happening
here is my image code of CSS, is I am doing something wrong ???
I want to get the double size of a button so how can I do that
here is my code

[image: the code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your code is incomplete or non-existent (we can't run it). Please read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

[image]

There is a *colon* after absolute instead of a *semicolon*, and that cancels out the next line: `top: 0;` which messes with the size of `.btn::after`.

So when you add a scale() transform on the `.btn::after` pseudo-element, it doesn't 'know' what to scale because the code that determines the size of the pseudo-element is invalid.

[image]

Comment: it works fine thank you a lot I m new in programming so thanks for your time

Comment: `position: absolute:` should be `position: absolute;`, do you see the difference?

Comment: t works fine thank you a lot I m new in programming so thanks for your time